# Fab middle in BottomNavigation in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, imagebutton, bottomnavigationview, floating-action-button

[image: Bottom Navigation with FAB on middle]

I have a requirement to implement bottom navigation control in android app.need to place FAB or any Action Button (ImageButton) middle in the navigation bar as on image. can someone please let me know how to do this.

Comment: This button is not for navigation

Comment: I think you can try the new BottomBar, it's available in the new support library